# Apache - Proxy external files to download

Tags: apache, plone, plone-4.x

Consider this:

- we have an external server for files that can be downloaded
- our website (plone based) is the interface for downloading them and we try to hide the direct links as much as possible
- jquery.fileDownload plugin needs a cookie set on file on download

I'm trying to set our Apache configuration to replace links like this:

- original: `data-files-example.com/folder/subfolder/file.zip`
- replaced: `our-website-example.com/_downloads/folder/subfolder/file.zip`

So, the missing part in my case is: how to set Apache to work like this?

I'm trying:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost :80>
    ServerAdmin email@our-website-example.com
    ServerName our-website-example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/_downloads(.)$" "https://data-files-example.com/$1" [P] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT|DELETE|PROPFIND|OPTIONS|TRACE|PROPFIND|PROPPATCH|MKCOL|COPY|MOVE|LOCK|UNLOCK)$

    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:/VirtualHostBase/http/data-files-example.com:80/my_plone_website/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]

</VirtualHost>
```

I receive `503 Service Unavailable`.

How to fix this?

Comment: You may generally have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I posted a link on the forum to your question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code at least rewrites your given original- to your desired target-URL:

```
<VirtualHost>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^our-website-example.com$
    RewriteRule   "^/_downloads(.*)$"  "https://data-files-example.com/$1"  [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This requires the modules `mod_ssl`, `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` to be activated.

Let us know if it was your sought solution and if not, where it went wrong :)

Comment: I receive This page does not seem to exist… - the plone page for missing content.

Comment: 404 (Not Found)

Comment: But you get http://our-website-example.com/_downloads/folder/subfolder/$1  with $1 = whatever you called after 'subfolder' ??? If not, there probably is another rewrite, redirect, proxypass, etc. in play... Can you post the exact URL u called and the one it got written to (except your actual domain ofc)

Comment: Still no solution? Maye we can continue the discussion in chat? Btw, there seems to be some confusion wether you want to rewrite from data-files-example.com to our-website-example.com/_downloads or the other way around...or a third way...

Comment: Still not working. I see this error in /var/log/httpd/error_log: [Tue Apr 04 zzz] [proxy:warn] [pid zzz] [client 79.zzz] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /_downloads/path/to/file.zip. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Comment: So you are using ProxyPAss directive as suggested by mschriefel? did you include the according apache proxy modules like proxy, proxy_http and more if you use other than the suggested ProxyPass functionalities...

Comment: The both answers (your and mschriefel's) - the same result. The strange part is http://demo.copernicus.eea.europa.eu/global (Global folder here) is working correct - use content from http://globland.vgt.vito.be/ and seems the same case for me. In the same conf file with rule `RewriteRule   "^/global(.*)$"  "http://globland.vgt.vito.be/$1"  [P]`. If I add my rule or if I replace it I get the error. Also tried with `filedownload` instead of `_downloads` and created as folder (similar to Global). So, I think the modules are included... How can I double check this?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/06NM7B7  proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared) Seems ok, right?

Comment: it definitely does :/  But what also caught my attention was this `/_downloads/path/to/file.zip` --> a zip.file. Maybe you have to set a handler in /etc/apache2/mime.types like `application/x-gzip gz` for gzip. Not that this seems to be the underlying problem, but just stumbled over it...

Comment: Did you turn up the LogLevel yet? `LogLevel error rewrite:trace2` restart and test again. Then look into error.log and search with `tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:' `  --> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139940/discussion-between-hello-fishy-and-ghitab).

Comment: Good. I wrote there.

Answer (score 2):

Try a reverse proxy. Just make sure that mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are enabled in your Apache configuration and that your proxy rule is set before the VirtualHostBase rule for Plone, if the pattern is the root slash.

```
ProxyPass         /_downloads     http://data-files-example.com
ProxyPassReverse  /_downloads     http://data-files-example.com
```

When proxying to a https backend you'll also need mod_ssl installed and the directive SSLProxyEngine On.

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass         /_downloads     https://data-files-example.com
ProxyPassReverse  /_downloads     https://data-files-example.com
```

Comment: This page does not seem to exist… 404 (Not Found)

Comment: `Just make sure that mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are enabled in your Apache configuration and that your proxy rule is set before the VirtualHostBase rule for Plone` ---> Did you make sure that both modules are loaded? The message you posted below `No protocol handler was valid for the URL[...]` seems like you didn't...

Comment: http://dpaste.com/06NM7B7  proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared) Seems ok, right?